# Pytesseract's OCR accuracy improvement

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an image & I had pre-process it as this

I used pytesseract for reading the image

The image is a window screenshot so i did not process it in any thresholding or grayscale

The rectangle is to hide the button which makes the OCR engine to focus on the number that i wanted

[image]

But somehow when it read, the result is some what accurate

The output it read after i had compile it into a list as

```
['0.2817', '0.2817', '0.71', '0.2490', '0.2', '0.2466', '0.2490']
```

the config i have for the OCR is `custom_config = r' --psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=..0123456789'`

Any suggestion that i can improve ?
Does darkening the line of the word improve the accuracy ?

Comment: The font is too small and the characters too close together.  if you got a screenshot, then you're on the same computer.  Why can't you read the data directly?

Comment: Because the screenshot i have is from another PC from another site, where their task is just get a screenshot, if the text is too small, how can i overcome this ?

Comment: Pytesseract does a better job if you can give it the exact font being used.  You should be able to find that out.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the font is too small, i found a better way for the OCR to recognize, by using zoom ```resize``` works well and can produce the output as desired